# ReSharper key bindings problem

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I use: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Resharer 6.

In ReSharper's options i choose Visual Studio keyboard sheme and click Apply Sheme:

[image]

After that some shortcuts are not assigned, such as: Go to Declaration, Go to implementation, Find Usages, Complete symbol, etc:

[image]

Try

- Tools -> Options, Environment -> Keyboard -> Reset
- Import and Export Settings, re-import C# developer settings
- devenv /reset

Nothing helped.

Configure shortcuts manually is not desirable.
Help, please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known issue that affects all ReSharper shortcuts that include F12 after switching from IntelliJ keymap to VS keymap. It's documented in [this bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-258219) that you're free to watch and vote for.
As far as I'm aware, the only workaround would be to reassign the broken shortcuts manually through Tools > Options > Keyboard.

Comment: If anyone has this issue in VS2012 - I just fixed it with Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, select 'Visual C# 2005' under 'Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme'. Then click 'Reset'.  This was infuriating, hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 139):

This one worked for me 100% after trying a bunch of other things:

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Press the (RESET) button
2. Go to ReSharper - > Options -> Keyboard & Menus -> Select the "Visual Studio" scheme -> Press "Apply Scheme"
3. Press "Save"
4. Press "CTRL-T". Since this shortcut is mapped in both VS and Resharper, you will be presented with the "Shortcut Conflict"-window. Here you select "Use ReSharper (Ultimate) command" and make sure to check the box "Apply to all ReSharper (Ultimate) shortscuts".

Voila!

Comment: In ReSarper 2017.13 the Keyboard & Menus are under Environment.
ReSharper - > Options -> Environment -> Keyboard & Menus.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  don't know how during a visual studio update my shortcuts got nuked, but thanks to your kind and knowledgeable words there are back!!!

Comment: This is still a problem - it happened to me on VS 2022 preview 5.0 with ReSharper 2021.3 EAP, and this solution still works - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Hpersw's solution works. in VS -> Tools -> Import & Export Settings -> Reset all settings and press finish. This should give you the shortcuts back

Comment: If I could upvote you twice I would. No other answer worked for me. +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

After wrestling with this for half a day and trying all of the options above, I finally found the magic setting that fixed MY problems: I UNSELECTED "Hide overriden Visual Studio Items" in Options/Keyboard and Menus"

Answer (score 5):

In VS go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Apply the following keyboard mapping schema: [Default]

Comment: This is a really old post...is this answer any better than the previous provided?

Comment: Yes... just had the same problem and none of the solutions posted here worked.

Answer (score 4):

**The easiest way** to solve this problem is :

> Go to: ReSharper -> Manage Options -> Reset All Settings

These steps gonna solve your shortcuts (key bindings) issues.

You **do not** have to keep performing the following actions:

```
1) Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Press the (RESET) button

2) Go to ReSharper - > Options -> Keyboard & Menus -> Select the "Visual Studio" scheme -> Press "Apply Scheme"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little old, but I just thought I'd share my epiphany... It seems that with Resharper 7x and VS2010 (probably anything later too), is best set when you op for the selecting the "Text Editor" as the settings to update under Options->KeyBoard. So, what I would recommend if you like some of Resharper features, use this site to get the shortcuts [Resharper Shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html.)

Then set them accordingly with Text Editor selected as the settings to update. Global does NOT seem to work consistently.

FYI- Text Editor works for C#, CSS and javascript. Not sure about other languages within VS.

Comment: Great tip on the "Text Editor" , this was driving me nuts. Using VS2015 and R# 9.1.1, NONE of the other solutions worked

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I wonder if Resharper is overriding `Global` shortcuts somewhere, so setting them to `Global` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation on [Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html):

To switch between two available keyboard schemes or restore the default state of your currently selected scheme

1. On the main menu, choose ReSharper | Options.
2. Select Environment | Visual Studio Integration.
3. In the Visual Studio Integration tab, select Visual Studio, ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA, or None, and click Apply Scheme. If you selected None, you can define an arbitrary set of custom keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio's native Options menu (Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard) - see To configure keyboard shortcuts above.

Also, here's some documentation on [how to resolve keyboard shortcut conflicts with Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Resolving_Keyboard_Shortcut_Conflicts.html)

Comment: Have you tried applying the ReSharper scheme to see if those key mappings work?

Comment: Yes, but the scheme does not fully apply

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because ReSharper provides its own e.g. "Go to Declaration" commands, and thus the Visual Studio shortcut is not configured? Try positioning the cursor at any symbol and press CTRL+B, which should launch the ReSharper version of "Go to Declaration".

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html
Shortcut (Visual Studio) for some commands, including "Go to declaration" written in black. Why? 
Press Ctrl + B  at any symbol but nothing happened.

Comment: In case it is simply because ReSharper has overridden the Visual Studio commands, and you cannot reset it, you might try to uninstall ReSharper. Or if you prefer the ReSharper keyboard shortcuts, see http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html and either http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper60DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf for the ReSharper keymap in Visual Studio Scheme, and http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper60DefaultKeymap_IDEA_scheme.pdf for the ReSharper keymap in ReSharper Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Doing "Reset All Settings" in VS Import&Export usually helps with restoring shortcuts. But it will, eh, reset all VS settings.