# ReSharper 8.1 (8.0, 7.1) hotkey schema doesn't have some hotkeys in MS Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, hotkeys, resharper-7.1, resharper-8.0, resharper-8.1

After installing **Visual Studio 2012** and **ReSharper 8.1** (8.0, 7.1), the second one asks for choosing hotkey schema. I choose **ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA**. After that in menu **ReSharper > Navigate** some menu items have hotkeys (such as Go to File Member), but some of them don't (Go To File, for example). [There is 34,2 KB](http://screencast.com/t/Ufj5B9NJYFH) picture on screencast. Search result by hotkey in keyboard option section confirms that. [There is (43.8 KB)](http://screencast.com/t/tbVPyPRYnjnf) picture.
All that looks like **ReSharper can't set hotkeys, which already are used by Visual Studio**, or ReSharper schema doesn't contain hotkeys for some actions.

So question is what can prevent hotkey setting process and is it possible to set all IDEA hotkeys at once?

I've tried methods described in following topics:
[Keyboard shortcuts are not active in Visual Studio with Resharper installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364059/keyboard-shortcuts-are-not-active-in-visual-studio-2012-with-resharper-installed)
[ReSharper key bindings problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375185/resharper-key-bindings-problem)
and there is no effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After month of pain and suffering without ReSharpers hotkeys I found solution. Before applying ReSharper hotkey scheme, it's nessesary to set **English language** as default input language of system. After that you should apply scheme and enjoy.